# Compiling libktx on Linux

Tags: linux, opengl, makefile

The OpenGL sdk recommends using libktx for loading textures on OpenGL, however the default makefile gives me the error

```
make: *** lib: No such file or directory.  Stop.
```

and moving the file to the project's base directory gives me

```
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/tim/Documents/ktx/lib'
make[1]: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

Is there an idiots guide to compiling libktx on linux?

Comment: "*The OpenGL sdk recommends using libktx for loading textures*" And there's your first mistake: listening to *anything* in the [OpenGL "SDK"](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/). `libktx` is only useful for loading images that are *in* the KTX format. Unless you've got a lot of data from OpenGL ES, you probably don't have KTX-formatted images, so it's probably not going to be useful to you.

Comment: My intention was to try and get it running and then convert some standard images to the ktx format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "lib" directory that is missing is build/GNUmake/lib. build/GNUmake/lib/GNUmakefile was inadvertently omitted from the zip and tar archives of the project. I apologize for that. I didn't notice because I always work in an SVN workarea.

The good news is that v2.0 of libktx has just been released. The zip and tar archives for contain the once missing file. You can find links to download the archives and a link to the SVN repository at the following web page.

http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/tools/KTX/

To compile on linux:

cd build/GNUmake
  make

In version 2.0 this will build versions of the library for OpenGL ES 1, 2 & 3 and for OpenGL.

Before doing this you will need to either change the macro glincdir to the parent directory of the GLES1, GLES2, GLES3 and GL include directories on your system. If there is some standard place for these include files on all Linux distributions, feel free to modify the GNUmakefile and send it back to me.

If you want to build only for one of the GL or GL ES versions

cd build/GNUmake/lib
  make es1 [or es2 or es3 or gl]

I've only tested on cygwin. Hopefully it will build as expected on GNU/Linux.

Comment: thanks for the feedback, sorry I didn't notice this earlier. I'll give it a try shortly